# Can I create a new version of my app while an earlier version is "Waiting for Review"?

Tags: app-store-connect

I have a version 1.0 of an iOS app that I submitted to Apple. I uploaded it to iTunes Connect and it is marked as "Waiting for Review".

I had to make a minor change, so I have a new version 1.0.1 which I would like to upload and get into the queue for approval. In the past when I want to make an update I can click "Add Version" under Versions on the iTunes Connect page for my app, but that option is not there for some reason.

Will I have to wait until my app is approved (or rejected) before I can create and upload my change? **Or, is there a way to avoid this so that I can reduce the time before my fixed version hits the Store?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can upload new binary, only you have to be aware that it will restart the whole 'waiting for review' process. Go to app details in itunes connect then to 'Binary Details' and there you should see 'Reject Binary' button in top right corner. After rejecting binary you'll be able to upload new one.